# Difference between two defintions of Heine-Borel Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

In class my notes gave the defintion of

Theorem (Heine- Borel): If {U <sub>λ</sub>: λ∈Ω} covers [0,1] then there is a finite set λ  <sub>1</sub>... λ<sub>n</sub> such that [0,1] ⊂ U  <sub>λ  <sub>i</sub></sub>    : {1≤i≤n}
which he states means 
"Every open cover of [0,1] has a finite subcover."

But my textbook gives the defintion:
A subset E of R <sup>k</sup> is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Could someone point out why this two are the same , because it seems to me that they are saying different things: specifically the textbook definition gives us if and only if but the definition my professor gave us is only one directional.

I know this is not the place to clarify something like this but I have been pondering over for days.. thank you! Pardon my English, Dutch is my first language.

Comment: They are not the same. The first theorem just says that $[0,1]$ is a compact set in $\Bbb R$. It is the second result that is normally called the Heine-Borel theorem.

Comment: So does the second statement include the first statement? I mean the first statement can be derived from the second?

Comment: Yes, it can; $[0,1]$ is clearly bounded, and it’s very easy to show that it’s also closed, so by the H-B theorem it’s compact.

Comment: but if [0,1] is bounded here, is [0,1) bounded too sir, because it seems that you said [0,1] is clearly bounded but why isn't it clearly closed

Comment: Yes, $[0,1)$ is also bounded, but it’s not closed. Whether it’s obvious that $[0,1]$ is closed depends on exactly what definition of closed set you’re using. In the context of subsets of $\Bbb R$ I can think of at least three different definitions that you might be using, all of which are equivalent for subsets of $\Bbb R$. With all of them it’s easy to check that $[0,1]$ is a closed set, but it’s not quite immediate. And the fact that it’s a closed interval is **not** enough — **unless** you’ve already proved that closed intervals are closed sets in the topological sense.

Comment: here when we are referring to [0,1], it seems that you are referring to it as a set, but isn't this an interval on the reals?

Comment: It is both: it is a set of real numbers, and those numbers happen to form a closed interval of real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The first of these is not the Heine-Borel theorem - in fact this is typically given as the *definition* of compactness! Other definitions, such as "$A\subseteq X$ is compact if every sequence in $A$ has a subsequence convergent in $A$", are equivalent to the one given, that every open cover of $A$ has a finite subcover.

The Heine-Borel theorem is particular to $\mathbb{R}^n$, and is exactly the second statement. Every compact set is both closed and bounded, but the converse is in general *not* true, and a common counterexample can be found by examining subsets of certain function spaces. The fact that $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies the important property that compactness is equivalent to closedness and boundedness is what the Heine-Borel theorem states.

(However, I should note that I have seen textbooks that call the first statement the Heine-Borel theorem as well, but I believe the convention I have mentioned above is the one most prevalent in analysis; if someone refers to the Heine-Borel theorem, they are almost certainly referring to the second statement and not the first.)

Comment: so in those textbooks you mention, the Heine-Borel theorem is the compactness theorem? This seems arbitrary, or is there a missing link ?

Comment: Why isn't the converse true, as isn't the statement if and only if?

Comment: I have seen the Heine-Borel theorem referred to as the first statement in Protter/Morrey's "A First Course in Real Analysis". However, every other textbook I've seen (Rudin, Abbott, Rosenlicht) have all referred to the Heine-Borel theorem as the second statement. And the statement _is_ an if and only if for $\mathbb{R}^n$ - a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. In an arbitrary metric space, this is not true.

Comment: For what reason some authors may decide to call the open covering result the Heine-Borel theorem I am not entirely sure - unfortunately I do not know enough of the history of the theorem to answer why that might be the case.

Comment: for [0,1] , is this a space in ℝ? Sorry if this is trival but I am confused now, because someone said that [0,1] is a Eucilidean space

Comment: Yes, $[0,1]$ is a Euclidean space - any subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with the usual notion of distance in $\mathbb{R}^n$) is a Euclidean space. So you could equivalently say that compactness is equivalent to closedness and boundedness in any Euclidean space.

Comment: just out of curiosity here, if something is not an Euclidean space, what kind of space is it? Because it seems it can only be an Euclidean space so why is there a notion of a different kind of space that people are trying to hint at

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107598/discussion-between-csch2-and-joseph-rock).